# Using "studied for" in this sentence considered wrong?

Tags: grammar, colloquialisms

I use Grammarly from time to time since I'm not a native speaker of English. I wrote this sentence,

> I studied for an exam, sat down in the exam hall, realized that it wasn't the exam I studied for.

Grammarly tells me that it's "inappropriate colloquialism" and I'm not quite sure if I get it.

Comment: Grammarly rarely knows what's going on.  Just use their suggestions as a hint that you should check your work for errors.

Comment: Note that you are missing an *and* between the second comma and *realized*. Without it, this sentence sounds very informal.

Comment: @MicahWindsor I meant for it to be very informal, actually. But, if I apply your suggestion, it'd be "I studied for an exam, sat down in the exam hall, and realized that it wasn't the exam I studied for." right?

Comment: Yes. That is more correct.

Comment: If the sentence does what you wanted it to do, ignore Grammarly.